# sales of last month in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on mysql and trying to achieve one result

I have one table A as CompanyName, Date, NetSales

I'm using this right now

```
select Companyname, SUM(netsales)
  FROM A 
GROUP BY A
```

But in result I want one extra column which will tell me about the sales of last month. I couldn't break the logic.

Can anyone help here ?

Thanks

Comment: post expected result with data

Comment: two types of grouping at the same time are not possible. I'd recommend to run separate query to summarize the total sales, without grouping.

Comment: @PathikVejani, please have a look here  prnt.sc/agr94h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to check the month of date column. If the month of date equals to last month, then sum the netsales.

**Query**

```
select company, sum(netSales) as netSales,
sum(case when month(CURDATE()) - 1 = month(`date`) 
       then netSales else 0 end) as lastMonthSales
from your_table_name
group by company;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for last month sales then you can add the `where` condition like

```
select Companyname, SUM(netsales)
FROM A 
WHERE yourdatecolumn >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
group by Companyname
```

Comment: That's possible, but I need both column in a query NetSales, Netsales(Lastmonth).   Nesales will give sum of all sales till now and Netsales(Lastmonth) will give me only last month sales.

Comment: @Kate:- Can you give some sample data and expected result?